# Making a function wait for a variable to be true (javascript)

Tags: javascript, callback, constants

I have this const which is triggered by an 'onclick' button in html:

```js
const showWebinar = (id) => {
    const yt_frame = document.getElementById("youtube_frame");
    yt_frame.setAttribute("src", `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`);
    yt_frame.style.display = "unset";
    dataLayer.push({'event': `${id}`});
}
```

I need it, once the button is clicked, to wait for the callback 'onReadyForServerApproval' (this callback is from the [SDK found here](https://github.com/pi-apps/pi-platform-docs). The HTML button looks like this:

`<button class="button_click" onclick="showWebinar('YIhYCRBDOUo')">Pay</button>`

where the class triggers the payment flow.

Is it possible to make 'showWebinar()' wait for the callback?

Thanks

Comment: sure, mark it `async` and `await` whatever is needed.

Comment: thanks for replying. how do I get async to work on a const?

Comment: Where is the API call? What @georg means is that you can mark the function `async` like `const showWebinar = async (id) =>` and then whatever the api call is you can do something like: `const response = await apiCall();`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now have this code (below) and when I press 'Pay with Pi' the video appears, without waiting for me to press 'Complete':
```<script>
const show = async (id) => {
const response = await transfer(); 
const yt_frame = document.getElementById("youtube_frame");
yt_frame.setAttribute("src", `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`);
yt_frame.style.display = "unset";
dataLayer.push({'event': `${id}`});            
}
async function transfer() {
}
</script>
<button onclick="show('YIhYCRBDOUo');">Pay with Pi</button>
<button onclick="transfer()">payPi</button>```